# How to restore default folders for Desktop, Downloads and Documents?

Tags: finder, recovery

I deleted the "Desktop", "Documents" and "Downloads" folders and emptied the Trash.

I don't need to restore the contents of these folders because everything is already backed up on my external drive, but now the folder themselves are not appearing or able to be added/restored. Nothing can be added to the Desktop, nothing can be downloaded because I've deleted these folders.

**How can I restore or create these deleted folders?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? The **ACLs** on those _directories_ are `group:everyone deny delete`, so how could you have deleted them?

Comment: Catalina 15.6. I deleted them by highlighting all of the said folders, putting them into the trash and then emptied it so now they're either deleted or inaccessible in some way because even after a boot in safe mode the desktop file cannot be opened because it isn't found.

Comment: By default, one cannot delete any of the default _folders_ in one's **Home** _folder_ as the **ACLs** are set to `group:everyone deny delete` Testing on a **macOS Catalina 10.15.6** system, I could not delete any default _folder_ in my **Home** _folder_. Even though I could drag them to the **Trash** and empty it, nonetheless, those _folders_ were not removed. Did you modify your filesystem by turning off **System Integrity Protection** and removing the **ACLs** on those _folders_? -  Have to tried opening **Terminal** and using the `mkdir` _command_?, E.g.: `mkdir Desktop Documents Downloads`

Comment: This is super weird! Finder doesn’t let you delete those folders since at least as far back as Lion, regardless of the status of System Integrity Protection. You normally have to use the Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If they don't exist, Documents and Downloads - just create a folder with those names in your home directory. I think you can do the same for the Desktop directory. Make a Desktop folder in your home directory.