# Recreate Documents folder that was deleted

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, mojave

How do you recreate a documents folder (Or desktop or downloads folder) after permanently deleting them. If someone deleted the documents folder and permanently removed it from the trash, how can you get it back?

When you try to create a new folder in the user's directory, it gets a message along these lines:
The name "Desktop" is already taken, please choose another one.

Restoring time machine, icloud, or 3rd party backup recovery software is not an option.
It was also on Mojave. I don't believe any of the ACLs have been removed/modified so I don't understand how the folders were deleted.

I have the same kind of situation as this:
[How to restore default folders for Desktop, Downloads and Documents?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400497/how-to-restore-default-folders-for-desktop-downloads-and-documents)

Comment: In **Terminal**, what is the _output_ of the following _command_: `ls -leO@d ~/Desktop ~/ Documents ~/Downloads`

Comment: For each one it says: 
0: group:everyone deny delete

Comment: What is the unedited _output_, not selective _output_?

Comment: In **Terminal**, if the output of the aforementioned _command_ shows that those _directories_ exist, then there is no need to recreate them.  If it's just that they do not show in the **Sidebar** of **Finder**, then just add them back.

Comment: lrwx------+ 1 Teagslee  staff  uchg 35 23 Oct 22:48 /Users/Teagslee/Desktop -> /Users/Teagslee/Dropbox/Mac/Desktop
 0: group:everyone deny delete
lrwx------+ 1 Teagslee  staff  uchg 37 23 Oct 22:48 /Users/Teagslee/Documents -> /Users/Teagslee/Dropbox/Mac/Documents
 0: group:everyone deny delete
lrwx------+ 1 Teagslee  staff  uchg 37 23 Oct 22:48 /Users/Teagslee/Downloads -> /Users/Teagslee/Dropbox/Mac/Downloads
 0: group:everyone deny delete

Comment: When I use cd documents or something it doesn't exist, and I have tried showing it in finder. It actually is shown in finder, but there is no location it points to.

Comment: Those are _symbolic links_ not _directories_.  Does `/Users/Teagslee/Dropbox/Mac/` have the target _folders_ and any contents in them?

Comment: If you try in terminal : `mv Desktop Desktop.link` then `mkdir Desktop`, is it ok?